# Regex between match string

Tags: python

Hey everyone I have a question. I am new with regex and I found it a little bit confusing about the match.
Let say I want to take the element between a pattern of number.

`['1.Ab2 C34 2.kj4 nsb', '1.Dog Cat4 2.Bird6 Trex5']`

Is it possible to just take whatever the element is between the number 1. and 2. ?

```
output = [[Ab2 C34], [Dog Cat4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.findall`:

```py
inp = ['1.Ab2 C34 2.kj4 nsb', '1.Dog Cat4 2.Bird6 Trex5']
matches = [re.findall(r'\b1\.\s*(.*?)\s*2\.', x)[0] for x in inp]
print(matches)  # ['Ab2 C34', 'Dog Cat4']
```

Comment: Hey why I got this error ? ```expected string or bytes-like object```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this using `search`.

```
import re
new = [[re.search('1.(.*)2.', s).group(1)] for s in ['1.Ab2 C34 2.kj4 nsb', '1.Dog Cat4 2.Bird6 Trex5']]
```